# view bottom part not tapable iOS 8

Tags: ipad, ios8

I am facing an issue with iOS 8 on iPad.each time I launch my app,its starts with landscape mode but mu app is in portrait mode only.To resolve this issue i have used code provided on Google.

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
//[self.window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Which solved my problem but now i am facing another issue where my view is showing black part at bottom.

If i uncomment last line in above code, my view run smoothly without black part but another issue which i am facing is now my view bottom part is not tapable.

My sign up and login and privacy policy buttons are not clickable now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It worked for me after changing window frame.                 [self.window setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];